# A proof for the inequality $\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}{\frac{1}{t+3i}} \leq \frac{1}{2} $ for all $t \geq 2$

Tags: inequality, summation

I'm struggling with proving the following inequality:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}{\frac{1}{t+3i}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

for all $t \geq 2$. I think it is monotonic non-increasing in $t$, which would suffice. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let $N=t-2$. We have:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{t-2}\frac{1}{t+3i}=S_N=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{N+3k+2}=\frac{1}{N+2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{1+3\frac{k}{N+2}} $$
and $S_N$ is greater than
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+3x} = \frac{2}{3}\log(2) =0.46209812\ldots$$
by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), but $S_0=\frac{1}{2}$ and $S_N$ is a decreasing sequence by [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) ($f(x)=\frac{1}{1+3x}$ is a convex function on $[0,1]$). A simpler alternative is given by comparing $S_N$ with $S_{N+3}$ then checking that $S_{N+3}\leq S_N$ and $S_1,S_2\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $f(t)$ be the sum. Show that $f(t+3) \leq f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not the integral test? We have $$\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}\frac{1}{t+3i}\leq\frac{1}{4t-6}+\int_{0}^{t-2}\frac{1}{t+3x}dx
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{4t-6}+\frac{1}{3}\log\left(4-\frac{6}{t}\right)
 $$ and now it is simple to prove that $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{4t-6}+\frac{1}{3}\log\left(4-\frac{6}{t}\right)
 $ is a monotonic increasing function if $t\geq3
 $ so

> $$\color{red}{f\left(t\right)\leq\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f\left(t\right)=\frac{\log\left(4\right)}{3}\approx0.462098.}$$